# SQL Azure transaction deadlocks or long running

Tags: sql, azure, dataset, deadlock, transactionscope

I'm working with a DataSet that holds different tables from a SQL Azure database. I'm using transactionScope to insert data into related tables (approx. 1-3 rows per table). 
In my database every insert operation is unique for every user, so there will be never duplicates.

In a test scenario I'm testing to parallely insert data and delete this data afterwards. Using TransactionScope for the delete operations I get deadlocks. When not using TransactionScope for the delete the delete statement takes sometimes up to 40 sec.
So seems like Azure is locking the whole table during insert and the delete has to wait ...

Is there a way to avoid that the operations take so long? Maybe in only using row locking or changing transactionScope options?

My Transaction:

```cs
var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();
transactionOptions.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
transactionOptions.Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout;
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, transactionOptions))
{
    InsertIntoTable1;
    InsertIntoTable2;
    InsertIntoTable3;
    scope.Complete();
}
DeleteTable3Entity;
DeleteTable2Entity;
DeleteTable1Entity;
```

Comment: Did you try "profiling" your app using the provided DMV (dynamic management views)?  It can let you know if you have deadlocks or other problems.  Furthermore, you also want to make sure your connections are not being throttled or other problems that could happen in a SQL Azure environment.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't work on the problem for a long time.I used SQL Server Management Studio to have a look at the table sys.event_log. I avoided the deadlock, by doing the delete operation outside of a transaction. But it takes a lot of time to delete a table (maybe because it is still locked by the insert transaction). How can I check this?